# Changing font in a two line figure title

Tags: matlab, line, title

I want to write my figure title in two lines in a way that I can change the text properties of both lines separately. I found:

```
title(['\bf{first line}' char(10) '\rm{second line}'])
```

which makes the first line bold. But how can I change the font size for first line?

Comment: check out this old but still very good package by Douglas Schwarz: [Styled Text Toolbox](http://www.frontiernet.net/~dmschwarz/stextfun/) (run the demo to see how powerful it is)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 title(['\fontsize{20pt}\bf{first line}' char(10) '\fontsize{10pt}\rm{second line}'])
```

I found this syntax hidden in the docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/adding-text-annotations-to-graphs.html#f0-19466
And then fiddled it bit.

Comment: +1 nicely found! I was trying `\Large`, etc... trust the `text` object to only support the nonstandard way of doing it in TeX...

Answer (score 6):

I'm with Dan, but I'd leave out the unintuitive `char(10)` and use vertically-concatenated cell-arrays:

```
title({...
    '\fontsize{25pt}\bf{first line}' 
    '\fontsize{8pt}\rm{second line}'
})
```

Result:

[image]

Nothing new, just a but more intuitive and readable.