# Matlab: changing font size on xlabel and ylabel

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, plot, visualization

I am doing the following (this is a simple example to illustrate the problem):

```
a = [1,3,4];
b = [1,4,5];
plot(a,b,'LineWidth',4);
xlabel('recall','FontSize',35);
ylabel('precision','FontSize',4);
```

and it produces:
[image]

As you can see the `'FontSize'` is having no effect. I have also got the properties of the xlabel shown below:

```
xl = xlabel('recall','FontSize',35);
get(xl)
    FontAngle = normal
    FontName = Helvetica
    FontSize = [35]
    FontUnits = points
    FontWeight = normal
```

Comment: Did you try a similar method to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16189031/two-line-title-in-matlab-figure ? It was asked an hour ago, works fine for xlabels too

Comment: @Dan just did, no luck :(

Comment: `xlabel('\fontsize{35pt}recall')`, it works for me

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem, please specify Matlab version and OS.

Comment: Matlab R2012b (8.0.0.783) 64-bit on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Comment: It seems to be localized, as I can't reproduce the problem on my Windows 7 laptop with same matlab version

Comment: Works fine here too (Windows 7/R2010 and Ubuntu 12.10/R2012)

Comment: Might it be font-related? have you tried changing the FontName?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install packages:

- xfonts-100dpi
- xfonts-75dpi.

as suggested in [this thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/326770#898664) because Ubuntu 12.04 doesn't come with MATLAB specific fonts.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Matlab R2014a. Installing these two packages does not seem to help. Is there perhaps an updated answer?

Comment: Works with Ubuntu 14.04 and Matlab R2013b. I don't hope this is an issue for more recent versions of Matlab.